# Bigger item overlaying TabLayout in Android

Tags: android, layout, android-tablayout

Currently I'm working on Android UI. Is the any ways or properties I can use to make a bigger tab item which can be overlay the Tablayout.

Like this Camera button:

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can custom each tab in TabLayout and add it to your TabLayout manually.
You read this post for clearer explanation.


http://www.android4devs.com/2015/12/tab-layout-material-design-support.html

Comment: @RoShanShan I already use the custom tablayout for my own, but have no idea how the tab item can overlay the border of tablayout like the above picture. :(

Comment: Check the view below

Answer (score 0):

YOu can try custom view like this, you can change the size relevant to your app

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="45dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <View android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1px"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"/>

    <View android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1px"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="35dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_camera"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:background="@android:color/white"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: So you mean to put another layout on top of TabLayout? I tried that but is it the best practice? I thought there is any ways to customize tab item's position.

Comment: No. This is the custom layout of TabLayout. I think if you want more complex UI, you can use your UI, no need to use TabLayout.